# how to code a notepad to auto run many programs with a delay?

Tags: batch-file, autorun

Sorry, this question is not well relevant to a programming language. But if you can help, thank you.

This is what I completely know about autorun a file,

```
[autorun]
;Open=LynxPortable.exe
ShellExecute=LynxPortable.exe
UseAutoPlay=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you should do something like this

```
@ECHO off
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hotspot Shield\bin\hsscp.exe"
timeout /t 30 >NUL
Taskkill /IM "hsscp.exe" /F
Exit
```